# Why my setInterval() is speeding up inside my React image slider?

Tags: reactjs

Why my interval is speeding up?
When I press any of my buttons **NextImage()** or **PrevImage(**) my interval starts speeding up and the image starts glitching. Any advice or help?
Here's my code =>

```
//Image is displayed
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState(1);
  let imageShowed;
  if (image === 1) {
    imageShowed = image1;
  } else if (image === 2) {
    imageShowed = image2;
  } else if (image === 3) {
    imageShowed = image3;
  } else {
    imageShowed = image4;
  }

  // Auto change slide interval
  let interval = setInterval(
    () => (image === 4 ? setImage(1) : setImage(image + 1)),
    5000
  );
  setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }, 5000);

  // Change image functionality
  const ChangeImage = (index) => {
    setImage(index);
  };
  / /Next image
  const NextImage = () => {
    image === 4 ? setImage(1) : setImage(image + 1);
  };

  // Previous image
  const PrevImage = () => {
    image === 1 ? setImage(4) : setImage(image - 1);
  };
```

Comment: OMG bro what is this, you shouldn't use your logic inside the component like this! wrap them inside the function and use react lifecycle like `useEffect` for rerender your component!!

Comment: add sample code in codesandbox for debugging is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach causes so many problems and you should learn more about `react` (watch youtube tutorials about react), I did make a working example slider hope to help you and people in the future:

```js
let interval;
const images = [
  "https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=1",
  "https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=2",
  "https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=3",
  "https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=4",
  "https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=5",
];
const App = () => {
  const [slide, setSlide] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      NextSlide();
      clearInterval(interval);
    }, 5000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [slide]);

  const ChangeSlideDots = (index) => {
    setSlide(index);
  };
  const NextSlide = () =>
    setSlide((prev) => (slide === images.length - 1 ? 0 : prev + 1));

  const PrevSlide = () =>
    setSlide((prev) => (slide === 0 ? images.length - 1 : prev - 1));

  return (
    <div style={styles.root}>
      <img style={styles.imageDiv} src={images[slide]} />
      <button style={styles.buttons} onClick={PrevSlide}>
        ◁
      </button>
      <div style={styles.dotDiv}>
        {images.map((_, i) => (
          <div
            key={i}
            style={i === slide ? styles.redDot : styles.blackDot}
            onClick={() => ChangeSlideDots(i)}
          >
            .
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button style={styles.buttons} onClick={NextSlide}>
        ▷
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
const styles = {
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    position: "relative",
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
  },
  buttons: {
    backgroundColor: "rgb(255 255 255 / 37%)",
    border: "none",
    zIndex: 2,
    flex: 1,
  },
  imageDiv: {
    position: "absolute",
    zIndex: 1,
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
  },
  dotDiv: {
    flex: 10,
    zIndex: 2,
    fontSize: "30px",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  redDot: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    color: "red",
  },
  blackDot: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    color: "black",
  },
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

When you need to have some logic which is `depend` on changing a variable, it's better to keep those logic inside `useEffect`

```
const interval = useRef(null);
const timeout = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
  interval.current = setInterval(
    () => (image === 4 ? setImage(1) : setImage((i) => i + 1)),
    5000
  );
  timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(interval.current);
  }, 5000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval.current);
    clearTimeout(timeout.current);
  }
}, [image]);
```

one point to remember is that if you use a `variable` instead of using `useRef` it can increase the possibility of clearing the wrong instance of interval or timeout during the rerenders. `useRef` can keep the instance and avoid any unwanted `bugs`

Comment: const interval can be placed inside useEffect without useRef.

Comment: @KirillSkomarovskiy no it can increase the possibility of clearing the wrong `instance` of `interval or timeout` during the rerenders. `useRef` can keep the `instance`

Comment: Check again your variable is local for useEffect. And never used outside useEffect so it can be used without useRef. If you have two useEffects that use interval you should use useRef. But in this example - no.

Comment: @KirillSkomarovskiy Check this answer Kirill, you would understand my point. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65831939/15045569

Comment: @ Weblandtk I've create sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-keller-72whk. First table is your solution with ref. Second table is solution without ref. And I add third table where I would show how make the same behavior but not clean up timerId and interval Id every value changes. Note that solution with ref and without ref create and clean timerId and intervalId too many times.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime that you rerender your component, you will run the whole function once. So you will set an interval every time you use setImage(). In order to prevent this, you have to use side effect functions. here you should use `useEffect()` because  you have a functional component. in order to make `useEffect()` only run once, you have to pass an empty array for dependecy array; So your useEffect will act like `componentDidMount()` in class components. try the code below:

```
let interval = null
    useEffect(() => {
        interval = setInterval(
            () => (image === 4 ? setImage(1) : setImage(image + 1)),
            5000
        )
        setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }, 5000)
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everybody for your great answers appreciated a lot your time and help!
So, my final solution looks like this:

```
const images = [image1, image2, image3, image4];
const quotes = [
  'Jobs fill your pockets, adventures fill your soul',
  'Travel is the only thing you buy that makes you richer',
  'Work, Travel, Save, Repeat',
  'Once a year, go someplace you’ve never been before',
];
const App = () => {
  //Image is displayed
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState(0);

  // Auto change slide interval
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearInterval(
        setInterval((interval) => {
          image === 3 ? setImage(1) : setImage(image + 1);
          clearInterval(interval.current);
        }, 5000)
      );
    };
  }, [image]);

  // Change image functionality
  const ChangeImage = (index) => {
    setImage(index);
  };

  //Next image
  const NextImage = () => {
    image === 3 ? setImage(1) : setImage(image + 1);
  };

  // Previous image
  const PrevImage = () => {
    image === 1 ? setImage(3) : setImage(image - 1);
  };

  return (
    <Section>
      <div className='slideshow-container'>
        <div>
          <img className='slider_image' src={images[image]} alt='slider' />
          <h1 className='slider_title'>{quotes[image]}</h1>
        </div>
        <button className='slider_prev' onClick={PrevImage}>
          &#10094;
        </button>
        <button className='slider_next' onClick={NextImage}>
          &#10095;
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          {images.map((image, i) => (
            <img
              key={i}
              alt={`slider${i}`}
              src={image}
              className='bottom_image'
              onClick={() => ChangeImage(i)}
            ></img>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Section>
  );
};
```